# When is the space of maps between varieties a finite CW complex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cont{Cont}$Given two algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ denoted by $X$ and $Y$ where $Y$ is projective and $X$ is either projective or affine/Stein. The space of continuous maps $\Cont(X,Y)$ with compact open topology is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex by a result of Milnor. I was wondering whether it is known when this CW complex is a finite one or not. If not can anything be said about the homology/homotopy groups of $\Cont(X,Y)$ and when they are finitely generated? Finally is the space of regular maps as a subspace also homotopy equivalent to a CW complex?

Comment: In the simplest case where $X$ is not one point, namely when $X$ equals  $\mathbb{CP}^1$, which is topologically a $2$-sphere, the space of continuous maps is essentially a "free double loop space" of $Y$.  Thus it is never a finite CW complex.